# Best practices for setting up Azure for a client and allow other devs access?

Tags: azure

Do I have the client setup an account using their payment, contact info etc? or do I use my own account then somehow transfer everything to the client? Also, How do I give access to devs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are different strategies you can employ to decide how you want to design and organize your Subscriptions. The [Subscription decision guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/decision-guides/subscriptions/) within the Microsoft Cloud Adoption Framework for Azure can help you establish that structure.

As for granting access to others, [Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) is a system that provides fine-grained access management of Azure resources. Using Azure RBAC, you can segregate duties within your team and grant only the amount of access to users that they need to perform their jobs. Instead of giving everybody unrestricted permissions in your Azure subscription or resources, you can allow only certain actions at a particular scope. You can further refer to the [best practices for Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/best-practices) doc to know more.